# Microsoft Sync Framework. Applying "Scope" to an existing SqlCe database

Tags: sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

Is it possible to apply a DbSyncScopeDescription to an existing SqlCeDatabase?

I'm trying to provision an existing database using a DbSyncScopeDescription built from this database.

This is the code i'm using to test this out.  This should give you an idea of what I'm trying to do.

I get a SqlCeException on the last line with the message:

"The specified index does not exist. [ sysChangeTxBsn_idx ]".

```
private void Test()
{
    DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDescription =
       new DbSyncScopeDescription("MyScope");

    foreach (string tableName in TableNames)
    {
        DbSyncTableDescription tableDecsription = SqlCeSyncDescriptionBuilder
            .GetDescriptionForTable(tableName, myConnection);
        scopeDescription.Tables.Add(tableDecsription);
    }

    SqlCeSyncScopeProvisioning scopeProvisioning =
        new SqlCeSyncScopeProvisioning(scopeDescription);
    scopeProvisioning.SetCreateTableDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.Create); 
    scopeProvisioning.Apply(myConnection);
}
```

Please let me know if this is possible or if I'm doing something wrong.  Thank you,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I would try is to use the [Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.synchronization.data.dbsynccreationoption(SQL.105).aspx) enumeration value in the call to SetCreateTableDefault.

```
scopeProvisioning.SetCreateTableDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.Skip);
```

The tables are already present in the database and you do not need to create them.

Also, I have had problems provisioning SQL Server Compact Edition databases in the past if change tracking has already been enabled.

Cheers,

Scott

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond.  I ended up resturcturing things so that I can apply scope to my SqlCe database when it is created.